# SQL select latest dates from a table based on category

Tags: sql, max

I have a requirement where table is like this

```
Id   code        TDate          Amount
--------------------------------------------
1    A01        11/23/2018       100.20
2    A02        10/25/2018        20.20
3    B01        11/24/2018        10.10
4    C01        11/25/2018        22.12  
4    D01        11/21/2018        22.12
```

I want to get latest date from group (A01, A02) as LATEST_DT_A and (B01, C01, D01) as LATEST_DT_X
Here Codes are well defined and fixed. I want to select latest date from each group.

This table has huge volume of data and using case statement is timing out.

Out put will be

```
Id   LATEST_DT_A    LATEST_DT_X
------------------   ---------
1    11/23/2018      11/25/2018
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Why is there `id = 1` in the result and not `id = 4`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Common Table Expression`, `CASE` and `MAX()` :

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Id  INT
    ,Code   VARCHAR(10)
    ,TDate  DATE
    ,Amount NUMERIC(18,2)
);

INSERT INTO #Temp
VALUES
 (1,'A01','11/23/2018',100.20)
,(2,'A02','10/25/2018', 20.20)
,(3,'B01','11/24/2018', 10.10)
,(4,'C01','11/25/2018', 22.12) 
,(4,'D01','11/21/2018', 22.12);


WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  Id
            ,CASE WHEN Code IN ('A01','A02') THEN TDate ELSE NULL END LATEST_DT_A 
            ,CASE WHEN Code IN ('B01','C01','D01') THEN TDate ELSE NULL END LATEST_DT_X  
    FROM #Temp
)
SELECT  MIN(Id) Id
        ,MAX(LATEST_DT_A) LATEST_DT_A 
       ,MAX(LATEST_DT_X) LATEST_DT_X 
FROM CTE
```

or simply `CASE` and `MAX()`

```
SELECT   MIN(Id) Id
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN Code IN ('A01','A02') THEN TDate ELSE NULL END) LATEST_DT_A 
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN Code IN ('B01','C01','D01') THEN TDate ELSE NULL END) LATEST_DT_X  
FROM #Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when code like 'A%' then tdate end) as latest_dt_a,
       max(case when code not like 'A%' then tdate end) as latest_dt_x
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation as :

```
 with tab(Id,code, TDate) as
          (
           select 1,'A01','2018-11-23' union all
           select 2,'A02','2018-10-25' union all              
           select 3,'B01','2018-11-24' union all              
           select 4,'C01','2018-11-25' union all
           select 4,'D01','2018-11-21'              
          )
   select min(Id) as id,
          max( case when substring(code,1,1) ='A' then TDate end )
          as latest_dt_a,
          max( case when substring(code,1,1)!='A' then TDate end )
          as latest_dt_x
     from tab;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/ELYCR53287)

P.S. For **Oracle** Database add `from dual` before `union all` keywords. Replace `substring` with `substr`,

For **MySQL** remove the part `with tab() as ( .... )`